# String column Length issue in a large table by fluent Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a strange problem which i am trying to fix since more than 2 days now.

I have a table with 236 columns, mapped using the fluent nHibernate.

```
            FluentConfiguration configuration = Fluently. Configure (). Database (pConfigurer).Mappings(m =>
                {
                    m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<T>();
                    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<T>();

                })
```

There are few columns which are text or varchar(max) or varchar(800) which are mapped using the length

```
  Map(x => x.ScDirectorFeeDesc).Column("sc_director_fee_desc").Length(2147483647)
```

All is well as long as i am **reading the values from the Database** even with the length more than 1000 or more.

I am facing a **problem when i am trying to modify that string which is more than 1000** and try to save or when i am trying to save a new value there, its kicking me with an exception...

```
Could not synchronize database state with session
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not execute batch command.[SQL: SQL not available] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandSet.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.SqlClientSqlCommandSet.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.SqlClientBatchingBatcher.DoExecuteBatch(IDbCommand ps)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.SqlClientBatchingBatcher.DoExecuteBatch(IDbCommand ps)
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteBatchWithTiming(IDbCommand ps)
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteBatch()
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session
```

I am using Fluent 1.3.0.733 and NHibernate 3.3.1.4000

If anyone knows the issue here please let me me that would be really helpful.

I tried mentioning the StringClob & Text SQLTypes in the mappings, i even tried changing the column type to 4000, but it doesnt just save it but throws the exception.

Thanks,
Sukumar

Comment: With so many columns - perhaps it is another column that is running into a length issue? Also - it doesn't matter how NH has the length mapped if the DB has a shorter length.

Comment: No the DB has a Column type of "Text" here SQL Server, so obviously its not shorter. I see the length attributes, etc which i mention in the fluent mapping class are being ignored.

Comment: What would be the possibility that the Length attributes are ignored in the above configuration, FluentConfiguration configuration = Fluently. Configure (). Database (pConfigurer).Mappings(m =>
                {
                    m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<T>();
                    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<T>();

                })

Comment: That seems a little odd as well. I'm not used to seeing two forms of mapping used.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are encountering is an SQL Server error, which would not happen with text/ntext and nvarchar(max) columns.

The issue might appear if the sum of all columns length (not including text/ntext/nvarchar(max)/xml/image) of a row exceeds the max row size (8060 bytes, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx )

You should sum-up the lengths of your columns definitions to see if it is more than 8060 (nvarchar count twice).
If so, you may have gotten a warning during table creation. You should have a look at the total length of the data you are trying to insert

Transforming the nvarchar(1000) to nvarchar(max) might be a solution.